# Покрытие матрицы

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как эффективно найти количество способов покрыть матрицу `n * m` прямоугольниками `2x2`, `1x2`, `2x1` так, чтобы все клетки были заняты и прямоугольники не пересекались?

Comment: Похожие вещи рассматривал Кнут в 4 томе "Искусства программирования", но как и что - не спрашивайте...

Comment: Можно прямым перебором, можно динамическим программированием ("динамика по профилю"), а вообще очень сильно зависит от задачи. Если это задача с соревнования - предоставьте, пожалуйста, ссылку на полное условие (со всеми ограничениями и так далее).